# How can I create keybindings to launch programs from a text console (with no window-manager / X display)?

Tags: shortcut-keys, virtual-console

What is a simple way (possibly requiring root access) to set-up hotkeys that I can press when using a console screen in order to run scripts or executable files?

"Console screen" means **not using Gnome, KDE, etc.** -- rather, using just a standard linux text console screen which can usually be accessed with a key-combination like Ctrl-Alt-F1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `loadkeys` to modify keys in the console (requires `sudo`).

Basically, you can dump you keys definition in a file:

```
dumpkeys > myfile.txt
```

Then edit this file, and search for the line that say `string F1 = "something"`
Replace something at your leisure, remember the final `"\n"` if you want the command executed:

```
string F1 = "ls -lR\n"
```

then reload the file with

```
sudo loadkeys myfile.txt
```

Now pressing F1 will be as if you typed `ls -lR` and the enter key.

There is a lot more info here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/create-function-keys-based-shortcut-to-speeding-up-work-at-linux-command-line-part-2.html

**A word of warning**: keep a copy of the original `dumpkey` file, as the change is global to all the virtual consoles and stable --- if you run a program that requires the normal definition of `F1` to work, it will not work unless you reload the original keymap before running it.

A cleaner and less "global" solution could be defining the commands in the shell (no superuser required): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200800/in-bash-how-do-i-bind-a-function-key-to-a-command